# Git creates huge temporary garbage objects

Tags: git

I'd like to use git locally to track changes to a few local files, dispatched over my home directory.

I initialised a repository at `~`, then added the few files with `git add`, and made a few commits. So far so good, `.git` is 300K large.

Problem is overnight, **`.git` grew to 5.4G**, filling my disk (*maybe it could grow more*). This happened twice : the first time, I re-created the repos, and the second time, `git prune` fixed it. Before pruning, `git count-objects -v` reported `error: garbage found: .git/objects/95/tmp_obj_...`.

Edit : One hour after posting, it had happened again (and I pruned again).

**Why does it happen, and how to fix it ?**

(I tried to group all these files in a single directory with links but could come up with a working solution that would keep the files at their desired locations, but if the problem really comes with the repos being at `~/`, then I would seek solutions in this direction.)

> git version 1.7.10.4 on Debian GNU/Linux wheezy/sid

Comment: Git doesn't do anything in the background. What was running "overnight" that told Git to do things?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't even think the files change during that time. Right now, without having run any git command since I posted, it grew to 18M, again with `error: garbage found: .git/objects/19/tmp_obj_...`.

Comment: git doesn't naturally have any background process to it, but maybe something strange happened. Does $: service --status-all give anything peculiar?

Comment: try ps -a and see if anything either git or cron have something strange going on. I've had plenty of git repos exerywhere so location normally shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17781/discussion-between-le-vieux-gildas-and-alex-shepard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had **[another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYNAT.gif) git repository [auto-commiting](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#GitSync) with cron**, the script of which had a **broken `cd`** in it (so it stayed in `~/`, and run *git add . >/dev/null*, and *commit*, from there).

<sub>Many thanks to Alex Shepard for his help in chat, which led to this being pinned down.</sub>